# SQL Date Formatting and Sorting Issue

Tags: sql-server

I want to return the year and then the end of the week and then group by the year and then the week ending.  The issue with this code is that it does everything except the sorting.

```
 SELECT datepart(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, PH.CreatedOn)) Year,  
    Convert(varchar(2), Datepart(month, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)), 101)  +  '/'  + Convert(varchar(2), Datepart(Day, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)), 101)  [Week Processed],
    COUNT(PH.new_purchasehistoryid) AS 'Registrations'
FROM new_purchasehistory PH
GROUP BY    DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, PH.createdon)), Convert(varchar(2), Datepart(month, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)), 101)  +  '/'  + Convert(varchar(2), Datepart(Day, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)), 101) 

ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, PH.createdon)) DESC, Convert(varchar(2), Datepart(month, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)), 101)  +  '/'  + Convert(varchar(2), Datepart(Day, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)), 101) desc
```

Here is the result. I think I need another digit. Is there a simpler way?

```
Year    Week Processed  Registrations
2016    2/6     5935
2016    2/27    4288
2016    2/20    4205
2016    2/13    3177
2016    1/9 10422
2016    1/30    3834
2016    1/23    3411
2016    1/16    2718
2015    9/5     8560
2015    9/19    6245
2015    9/12    7427
2015    8/8     6489
2015    8/29    6558
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make life easier with sub-selects. In case the colums you order by need to be in the selection then you need another sub-select.

```
SELECT
   T.year,
   Convert(varchar(2), T.month, 101) + '/' +  Convert(varchar(2), T.day, 101) Week,
   COUNT(*) Registrations
FROM (
   SELECT
      datepart(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, PH.CreatedOn)) Year,  
      Datepart(month, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)) Month,
      Datepart(Day, DATEADD(D, -1 * DATEPART(dw, PH.createdon) + 7,  PH.createdon)) Day
   FROM new_purchasehistory PH
) T
GROUP BY T.Year, T.month, T.day
ORDER BY T.Year DESC, T.Month DESC, T.Day DESC
```